# EF with database with no PKs - Good idea/Bad Idea/Fuhgeddaboudit

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, orm

There is so much conflicting and confusing advice all over the web about this. And I would like to settle this for myself and for any one who will be looking for such information in future.

Question is — Will Entity frame work work well with database that has tables with no Primary keys.

Detail : I have a database and it has lots of tables that don't have a PK specified. Call it bad design or whatever, but there is nothing I could do to change the schema now. I have to work with it. And we would like to use EF because we like MS and we work with MS tools all the time. We sleep much easier knowing MS will keep updating and supporting this EF, with its full attention in future. Okay here now is my burning question which I have researched excessively on this website and others. "Can I use EF in my project fully knowing that my DB has some tables that will never have PKs" . Part of the problem is we really want to use EF for ease of use and we being MSphiles.

I have heard lot of advice ranging from:

1. It wont work.
2. It can be made to work.
3. Not a big deal at all...

That's where it gets really sick. Please advise.

Comment: Why you really want to do that?

Comment: Like I said, if we can do this with EF , thats our first choice. I am open to any other good/solid alternatives.

Comment: It can be done when there are candidate keys (composite keys allowed). You must be 100% certain that these keys will always apply. That's probably what makes people suspicious. I can't blame them.

Comment: Any database with no primary keys is probably in the Fuhgeddaboudit category.  If there are unique keys (constraints) on each table not marked formally as primary keys, you're OK.  If there simply aren't unique constraints on (most of) the tables, the design is so woefully broken that it does not bear thinking about.  And these comments aren't tied to EF or any other technology; it is an assessment of the database design. Practically, the second question when designing a table should be 'what is the primary key?'. (The first question is 'what is the table representing or storing?' of course).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it largely depends on how you intend to use it.  Without a primary key, you can't have referential integrity.  So, in effect you can't have automatic lookups of subtables and such.

You can do manual joins of tables, and that should work.. but that severely limits the functionality of EF.

But here's the thing, nothing we say can convince you.  What will convince you is doing it yourself.  Build a test database, and a test app.  Setup your EF database.  See if it works for you.

Comment: I can test  it using EF like you mentioned, but it is hardly going to give me a realistic assessment of the huge/complex db I will be handling in the real project.Is nHibernate a good candidate for my situation (no PKs) then? I am still not getting a concrete answer from any one :-)

Comment: @Ohark - A huge complex db without primary keys is essentially random noise.  You have no way to identify any columns as unique, no constraints to ensure uniqueness, etc.. Writing SQL to deal with this would be a mess as well.  I doubt any other ORM will be better suited, as they all are based on primary keys.

Comment: how about linq to sql? any thoughts on this option? thanks for your help

Comment: @Ohark - same issue if there are no PK no tool will help you - you have to define PKs and most tools assume some degree of competent data design and no PKs shows no degree of competent design. The only way to improve things is improve the db so a tool can then work